# Hostgator pointing subdomain CNAME to Heroku yields "Heroku | No Such App"

Tags: heroku, subdomain, cpanel

Trying to point my HostGator hosted subdomain `portal.newaya.com` towards my Heroku app at `newaya.herokuapp.com`.  According to Heroku's documentation, everything seems to be set up properly.  However, I get a 'no such app' page when going to the subdomain.  The Heroku URL works fine.

My cPanel record has the subdomain pointing as it should be (I can't post a picture without 10 reputation points).

Here's my CNAME record in cPanel:

> portal.newaya.com.    14400   IN  CNAME newaya.herokuapp.com

Here's the result of the host command in my terminal:

> $ host portal.newaya.com
>
> portal.newaya.com is an alias for newaya.herokuapp.com.
>
> newaya.herokuapp.com is an alias for us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com.
>
> us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com has address 184.73.167.20

Comment: Possibly you either have a typo in where your subdomain is pointing to, or a typo in your domains section of Heroku settings. Can you verify those two?

Comment: Thanks Mike, here's the exact text of my CNAME record:

'portal.newaya.com. 14400 IN CNAME newaya.herokuapp.com'